# Error-Message after update Smarty v2 => Smarty v3 (CiciCRM 5.71.1, Joomla)

Tags: joomla, smarty, smarty3

following the instructions on the CiviCRM status page, I have added this code in civicrm.settings.php to update on Sparty v2 to v3:

```
define('CIVICRM_SMARTY_AUTOLOAD_PATH',
'/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/www.mywebsite.com/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Afterwards I get this error message:

```
rtrim(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
Call stack
#   Function    Location
1   ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php:1416
2   rtrim() JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php:1416
3   Smarty->_normalizeTemplateConfig()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php:812
4   Smarty->getTemplateDir()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php:1347
5   Smarty->__get() JROOT/media/civicrm/ext/mosaicotweaks/mosaicotweaks.civix.php:99
6   _mosaicotweaks_civix_civicrm_config()   JROOT/media/civicrm/ext/mosaicotweaks/mosaicotweaks.php:12
7   mosaicotweaks_civicrm_config()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:276
8   CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:194
9   CRM_Utils_Hook->commonInvoke()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/Joomla.php:86
10  CRM_Utils_Hook_Joomla->invokeViaUF()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:314
11  Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:251
12  Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73
13  Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:263
14  Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:168
15  CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:1494
16  CRM_Utils_Hook::config()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php:107
17  CRM_Core_Config::singleton()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:66
18  civicrm_initialize()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:87
19  civicrm_invoke()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php:40
20  require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:71
21  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher::Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\{closure}()  JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php:73
22  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
23  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143
24  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186
25  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
26  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:61
27  require_once()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:32
```

Unfortunately, I have not found an answer while searching here in the forum and also via Google. Do you have any tips for me?

If I comment out the code in civicrm.settings.php again, everything works.

Hier ein paar Infos zu unserer Konfiguration:

- Joomla 4.4.3,
- CiviCRM 5.71.1
- Ubuntu-Server
- PHP 8.2.16
- Action Provider 1.140
- AuthX 5.71.1
- CiviCampaign 5.71.1
- CiviCase 5.71.1 (deactivated)
- CiviContribute 5.71.1
- CiviEvent 5.71.1
- CiviMail 5.71.1
- CiviMember 5.71.1
- CiviReport 5.71.1
- CiviGrant 5.71.1 (deactivated)
- CKEditor4 5.71.1
- TinyMCE 1.5
- CiviMobileAPI 6.3.0 (deactivated)
- iATS Payments 1.8.0
- CiviMobile 3.0 (deactivated)
- Contribution cancel actions 5.71.1 (deactivated)
- Form Processor 2.0.5
- Custom search framework 5.71.1
- Mosaico Tweaks 1.4
- Form Core 5.71.1
- FlexMailer 5.71.1
- SearchKit 5.71.1
- Mosaico 3.5.1709296836

Do you need any further information?

Thank you, Zenon

Answer (score 0):

Its a known issue for Mosaico Tweak extension. I have raised a [PR](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mosaicotweaks/-/merge_requests/2) for the fix.

You can apply the [patch](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/mosaicotweaks/-/merge_requests/2.patch) or [download](https://lab.civicrm.org/pradeep/mosaicotweaks/-/archive/master/mosaicotweaks-master.zip) from my forked version until the PR is merged and released.